# What calls ListViewItem_ItemChecked event?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, listview, invoke, listviewitem

I have a ListView, checkboxes = true, View = List.  On the start of the project, I go through, do some calculatations and determine if the database is empty and what I should do from there.  Well one thing I do is iterate through an array (from a dll) of Report Names and add the list view items to the ListView because we want it to be as dynamic as possible.  In the ListViewItem_ItemChecked event if the application is just starting up (`If Not _bShowAll Then`) I just let it pass through, otherwise I call an "expensive" function.  When I go to start my application, it seems to be taking quite a while, so I put a break point in the "expensive" function and it is getting hit as many times as there are Report Names.  I know ListViewItem.SelectedItem if set will invoke the ListViewItem_ItemChecked, as well as ListViewItem.Checked and I think a few others.  But from initialization, the only function I call for a ListViewItem is insert.  And when I put a break point in my ListViedItem_ItemChecked, I hit the breakpoint.  Heres my Constructor, the ListViewItem_ItemChecked, and the "expensive" function.

```
Public Sub New()
    'Initializes all of the controls on the screen and their properties.'
    InitializeComponent()
    'Sets the variable to what the Window text is at Startup'
    _strTitle = Me.Text

    'ViewModes is a dll that contains Class ViewModes and a variable ViewModes.'
    'Goes through the Dictionary(Of string, String) and adds all of the keys to the View Mode ComboBox.'
    For Each kvp As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In ViewModes.ViewModes.ViewModes
        cmbViewMode.Items.Add(kvp.Key)
    Next

    'Sets the View Mode ComboBox to the first item that was added to it.'
    cmbViewMode.SelectedIndex = 0

    lblFigureTitle.Text = "ALL"

    _bShowAll = True

    For Each strReportName As String In _dataController.ReportNames
        lvReports.Items.Insert(lvReports.Items.Count, strReportName)
    Next

    _bShowAll = False

    'Check to see if the database has any information or not.'
    If Not _dataController.DatabaseIsEmpty Then
        'There''s no point in doing the stuff in this block if the database is Empty'

        'Sets the lable next to "IPB:" to the IPB obtained from the first record of the .out file.'
        lblIPBNumber.Text = _dataController.IPBNumber
        'Adds the IPB Number to the Window text so if it is minimized and the user has multiple'
        'instances of the app running, they can know which one is which by hovering over the bar in the Taskbar.'
        Me.Text = _strTitle + "    IPB: " + _dataController.IPBNumber
        'This builds the TreeView with the Figure names.'
        BuildFigureTree()
        'This goes through the data in the database and builds the list of reports'
        'BuildReports()'
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub lvReports_ItemChecked(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.ItemCheckedEventArgs) Handles lvReports.ItemChecked
    If Not e Is Nothing Then
        If cbAllReports.Checked Then
            If Not e.Item.Checked Then
                cbAllReports.Checked = False
                e.Item.Checked = True
            End If

            _lstReportFilter.Add(e.Item.Name)
        Else
            If e.Item.Checked Then
                _lstReportFilter.Add(e.Item.Name)
                cbTaggedRecords.Checked = False
            Else
                _lstReportFilter.Remove(e.Item.Name)
            End If
        End If
    Else
        For Each lvi As ListViewItem In lvReports.Items
            lvi.Checked = False
        Next
    End If

    For Each rr As ReportRecord In _lstReportRecords.Where(Function(rRecord As ReportRecord) _lstReportFilter.Contains(rRecord.Description))
        _strReportFilter += If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(_strReportFilter) Or _strReportFilter = "-1", "", ",") + rr.PartID.ToString()
    Next

    If Not _bShowAll Then
        FillDataGridView()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub FillDataGridView()
    'Set the cursor to a wait cursor just in case it takes some time retrieving information from the db'
    Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
    Try
        'We always want to make sure both scroll bars are visible'
        dgvParts.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Both

        Dim strFilter As String = String.Empty

        'If there is a value in the Search TextBox, add it to the filter'
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(_strSearchFilter) Then
            strFilter += If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(strFilter), " ", " and ") + _strSearchFilter
        End If

        'For us to filter on Figures, there has to be nodes in the tree.'
        If tvFigures.Nodes.Count > 0 Then
            'If the FigureTitle text equals "ALL" (set whenever a tree node is selected)'
            'then we don''t need to set a filter for figure.'
            If Not lblFigureTitle.Text = "ALL" Then
                'cbCurrentFigure is naturally not checked.  And we don''t want to filter on just that figure'
                'if the user isn''t searching for something.  So if there is a value in the search box and'
                'cbCurrentFigure is checked, then we want to look at only the selected figure.  However,'
                'if the search box is empty and cbCurrentFigure is not checked, we also want to search'
                'only on the selected figure.'
                If (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(_strSearchFilter) And cbCurrentFigure.Checked) Or (String.IsNullOrEmpty(_strSearchFilter) And Not cbCurrentFigure.Checked) Then
                    strFilter += If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(strFilter), " ", " and ") + Constants.TransformColumnOrHeaderName("Figure") + " = '" + tvFigures.SelectedNode.Name + "'"
                End If
            Else
                strFilter += If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(strFilter), " ", " and ") + Constants.TransformColumnOrHeaderName("Figure") + " LIKE '%%' "
            End If
        End If

        'A selection of an indenture level in the combo box means we need to add a filter.  "ALL"'
        'is not a selection and needs no filter.'
        If Not cmbIndentureLevel.Text = "ALL" And Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(cmbIndentureLevel.Text) Then
            strFilter += If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(strFilter), " ", " and ") + Constants.TransformColumnOrHeaderName("Indenture") + " = " + cmbIndentureLevel.Text
        End If

        'If the user has selected any of the reports in the list view, add those to the filter.'
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(_strReportFilter) Then
            strFilter += If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(strFilter), " ", " and ") + " PART_ID IN (" + _strReportFilter + ")"
        End If

        'If there is no filter, then we don''t want to view anything.'
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(strFilter) Then
            'If there are validation errors from importing the file, we want to display those errors and get out.'
            If _lstValidationResults.Count > 0 Then
                dgvParts.DataSource = _lstValidationResults

                For Each col As DataGridViewColumn In dgvParts.Columns
                    col.DataPropertyName = "ErrorMessage"
                    col.Visible = True
                    col.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Programmatic
                    col.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.ColumnHeader
                Next

                dgvParts.AutoResizeColumns()
                Return
            End If

            Dim bSource As BindingSource = New BindingSource()
            'We use the text from the View Mode combo box to look in a dictionary and obtain'
            'the query needed for that view.  We also send the filter so we get ONLY what we'
            'need when we''re pulling the data, instead of pulling it all and then filtering.'
            bSource.DataSource = _dataController.PopulateDataGrid(cmbViewMode.Text, strFilter).Tables(0)

            dgvParts.DataSource = bSource
            dgvParts.Columns(0).Visible = False
            'The Description Column should only be 250 characters in size.  If a description is longer'
            'than that, they need to double click the cell and a message box will pop up.'
            dgvParts.Columns("Description").Resizable = DataGridViewTriState.False
            dgvParts.Columns("Description").Width = 750

            For Each col As DataGridViewColumn In dgvParts.Columns
                'Programmatic sorting means custom sorting.  May be changed to automatic.'
                col.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Programmatic

                'Again, we don''t want to resize the description column, it should stay set.'
                If Not col.Name = "Description" Then
                    dgvParts.AutoResizeColumn(col.Index)
                End If

                'Because the Tags column is only reported, we do not want them to change any values'
                'in the column.'
                If col.Name.ToUpper() = "TAGS" Then
                    col.ReadOnly = True
                End If
            Next

            'Other row and cell properties.'
            dgvParts.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.DisplayedCells
            dgvParts.ShowCellToolTips = True
            dgvParts.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D
        End If

        FormatCells()

        'The information from here until the Catch statement goes through and counts how'
        'many records for each report there are and to set those counts into the items'
        'in the list view.'
        Dim nTotalCount As Integer = 0

        For Each lvi As ListViewItem In lvReports.Items
            Dim nCount As Integer = _lstReportRecords.Where(Function(rr As ReportRecord) lvi.Text.Contains(rr.Description)).Count()
            nTotalCount += nCount
            lvi.Text = If(lvi.Text.Contains("("), lvi.Text.Substring(0, lvi.Text.IndexOf("(") + 1), lvi.Text.Trim() + " (") + nTotalCount.ToString() + ")"
        Next

        cbAllReports.Text = If(cbAllReports.Text.Contains("("), cbAllReports.Text.Substring(0, cbAllReports.Text.IndexOf("(") + 1), cbAllReports.Text + " (") + nTotalCount.ToString() + ")"
        cbTaggedRecords.Text = If(cbTaggedRecords.Text.Contains("("), cbTaggedRecords.Text.Substring(0, cbTaggedRecords.Text.IndexOf("(") + 1), cbTaggedRecords.Text + " (") + _lstReportRecords.Where(Function(rr As ReportRecord) rr.Description.Contains("Tagged")).Count().ToString() + ")"
    Catch ex As Exception
        'An exception was thrown.  Show it to the user so they can report it.'
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
    'Change the cursor back to the default cursor'
    Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
End Sub
```

I made sure _bShowAll is True (meaning pass through the ItemChecked function) before inserting the items into the ListView and False afterwards, but I still hit the ItemChanged function.  Can anyone see something I'm missing, a way to make it easier, or is there a way to insert an item without invoking the ItemChecked method?  Thanks.

**UPDATE:** Nevermind everyone.  I found [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.itemcheck.aspx) which says that it invokes the method when the CheckBoxes property is set to true.

Comment: WinForms, WPF, or Silverlight?

Comment: System.Windows.Forms (if that's what you mean by WinForms).

Comment: ListView doesn't have an ItemChanged event.  No idea what you're talking about.  Post a *minimum* repro code sample.

Comment: @Hans - It's a moot point now.  I meant to put ItemChecked.  But I found the issue.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what it was and it wasn't anything in my code. For whatever reason, setting CheckBoxes property to True in the designer will invoke the ItemChecked event after the main constructor is called. I'm not sure why Microsoft does that, but whatever. :)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do is look at the call stack when you're on the breakpoint you've set. Scroll up far enough and you should see your own code. Click on that part of the stack trace and the IDE will take you to the line of code causing your problem.

Comment: I found out what it was and it wasn't anything in my code.  For whatever reason, setting CheckBoxes property to True in the designer will invoke the ItemChecked event after the main constructor is called.  I'm not sure why Microsoft does that, but whatever.  :)  Thanks for the answer.